# fading effect with centered horizontal list of images

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with a width set to 100%. Inside the container, there is a wrapper div centered with a height of 80% 
and a dynamic number of images listed horizontally with `inline-block`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.testimg{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#testDiv{
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
.testimgdiv{
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv">
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
        <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
        <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
        <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
        <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
        <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
        <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the last image on the left and last image on the right to have a fading effect and not cut like shown in jsfiddle. Sort of like a carousel. Is there a way to do this with just css and html?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a linear gradient background applied to generated content `:before` and `:after` `#testDiv`

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#testDiv {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.testimgdiv {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.testimg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#testDiv:before,
#testDiv:after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#testDiv:before {
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255));
}

#testDiv:after {
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="testDiv">
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
      <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
      <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
      <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
      <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
      <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class='testimgdiv'>
      <img class="testimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think I asked the question in a wrong way, this is a good solution, however is it possible to apply this effect on the left and right of the wrapper div?
So all images passing through left and right get the same effect

Comment: That works just fine in my case, thank you for your answer.